# What exactly is the output in my terminal when I try to use Alt+Delete to remove text?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, console, konsole

Alt+Backspace works in terminals which often leads to me mistakenly trying Alt+Delete which then adds a `~`. What exactly is happening there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a remnant of unrecognized scan-code.

A button on a keyboard sends one or several bytes indicating which button was pressed. These bytes are going through keyboard driver, which does some conversion, and eventually caught by the application (terminal in this case). The application is trying to recognize which hot key is that set of bytes is and act accordingly. If not recognized, application usually ignores such string, or you can have a "strange behavior".

To learn which bytes you are getting for which button or combination of buttons you can do `cat /dev/tty`. It will print you a set of symbols for each button - as the driver reports them to an application.

After you learn which combination of symbols are sent for that particular combination of buttons you can go to application's configuration file and add it, or fix it if the app is expecting different set of characters for a hotkey.

Due to a historically large variety of physical terminals with different keyboards, there are many variations of possible scan codes for the logically same keys. So the database `terminfo` came into being. It knows a lot of actual terminals (physical ones) and knows which string of characters is sent for which key combination. And if you want to teach your terminal a new hotkey, you would need to write you own terminfo entry, and choose with `TERM` environment variable.

The fact that you seeing just one symbol `~`, means your current terminal with your current TERM somehow recognizes and does something with part of the string sent by keyboard driver to the terminal, and prints the remaining part of the sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Bonus question - do you know if there's any way to make `Alt+Delete` work to delete by word in the terminal? If so, I assume it might vary by terminal?

Comment: Well... standard `xterm`,  has the Alt+D to delete word forward. Reassigning it is possible, but not triviial.